# Validation form is not working during signup

Tags: java, javascript, html, database, servlets

I created a html SignUp page with validation in javascript.
Here is the validation code.

## SignUp.html

<*script type="text/javascript"*>

```
function validateForm() { 
var id = document.signup.LoginId;
var password = document.signup.LoginPassword;
var cpassword = document.signup.ConfirmPassword;
var city = document.signup.City;
var state = document.signup.State;
var number = document.signup.PhoneNumber;
var email = document.signup.Email;
var address = document.signup.Address;
var zipcode = document.signup.ZipCode;

if(id.value == "") {
    window.alert("Error: Username should be filled out.");
    id.focus();
    return false;
}
re = /^\w+$/;
if(!re.test(id.value)) {
    window.alert ("Error: Username must contain only letters, numbers and underscores.");
    id.focus();
    return false;
}

if(id.length < 6) {
    window.alert("Error: Username must contain at least 6 charecters.");
    id.focus();
    return false;
}
if(id.length > 12) {
    window.alert("Error: Username must not be greater than 12 charecters.");
    id.focus();
    return false;
}

if(password.value != "" && password.value == cpasswotd.value) {
    if(password.length < 6) {
        window.alert("Error: Password must contain at least 6 charecters.");
        password.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if(password.length > 12) {
        window.alert("Error: Password must not be greater than 12 charecters.");
        password.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if(password.value == id.value) {
        window.alert("Error: Password must be different from UserName.");
        password.focus();
        return false;
    }
    re = /[0-9]/;
    if(!re.test(password.value)) {
        window.alert("Error: Password must contain at least one number.");
        password.focus();
        return false;
    }
    re = /[a-z]/;
    if(!re.test(password.value)) {
        window.alert("Error: Password must contain at least one lowercase letter (a-z).");
        password.focus();
        return false;
    }
    re = /[A-Z]/;
    if(!re.test(password.value)) {
        window.alert("Error: Password must contain at least one uppercase letters (A-Z).");
        password.focus();
        return false;
    }
}else {
    window.alert("Error: Please check that you've entered and Confirmed your Password.");
    password.focus();
    return false;
}
window.alert("You have entered a valid password: "+password.value);
return true;



if(city.value == "") {
    window.alert("City must not be null.");
    city.focus();
    return false;
}

if(state.value == "") {
    window.alert("State must not be null.");
    state.focus();
    return false;
}

if(number.value == "") {
    window.alert("Phone number must not be null.");
    number.focus();
    return false;
}

if(number.length != 10) {
    window.alert("Phone number must be 10 digits.");
    number.focus();
    return false;
}

if (email.value == "")
{
    window.alert("Please enter a valid e-mail address.");
    email.focus();
    return false;
}

if (email.value.indexOf("@", 0) < 0)
{
    window.alert("Please enter a valid e-mail address.");
    email.focus();
    return false;
}

if (email.value.indexOf(".", 0) < 0)
{
    window.alert("Please enter a valid e-mail address.");
    email.focus();
    return false;
}

re = /^\w+$/
if(!re.test(address.value)) {
    window.alert("Error: Address must contain only letters, numbers and underscores.");
    address.focus();
    return false;
}

if(zipcode.value == "") {
    window.alert("Error: Zipcode must not be null.");
    zipcode.focus();
    return false;
}

if(zipcode.length > 6) {
    window.alert("Error: zipcode must not less than 6 digits.");
    zipcode.focus();
    return false;
}
```

}
<*/script*>

When i try to enter wrong email address like "sapan@2" or "sapan" it is not showing any error message, it is saved into the database.

Can anybody help me to fix this.

Thank You.

Comment: Can you post the entire function declaration?  That would help me help you.  :)

Comment: Sorry, i am unable to post the question completely. I am unable to insert html code. :-(    can you tell me how to post html code. That will help to me. Thank you.

Comment: Just the javascript code will be fine.  If you cannot post the entire function then I won't be able to help.  :)

Comment: ok, i did it. Is this you asked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a simple test signup form and attached the validation handler with jQuery. You can modify this test handler for your needs.

Put the following code in SignUp.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="myForm" name="myForm" action="" method="post">
      Username: <input type="text" id="username" value="" />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" />
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $( "#myForm" ).submit(function( event ) {

          if ( $( "input#username" ).val() != "" ) {
            alert('Logging you in!');
            return;
          }

          alert( "Please enter the username!" );
          event.preventDefault();         
        });

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

For this to work, you need to place jquery.min.js in the same folder as the html file.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things that may be wrong.

First, if you are calling the 'validateForm' function from an 'input' control of 'type="submit"', change it to be 'type="button"'.

Second, at the end of your 'validateForm' function, add the following line...

```
document.getElementById("yourformidhere").submit();
```

This will stop your form from submitting when the button is clicked, and will only submit the form, after all element values have passed validation, which is what you actually want to accomplish.

Comment: Please elaborate.  This should work unless you are running into different errors.

Comment: I didn't enter even username after modifying the code, then it is not showing any error indicating that "username should not be empty". nothing happened. It didn't show any error at all.

Comment: you mentioned "yourformidhere", right? means SignUp.html or id?

Comment: The 'id' of your form.  For instance, if you have '<form id='myForm'> on your page, then in the javascript, you would put, document.getElementById("myForm").submit();

Comment: Also, you need to learn how to debug javascript using your browser 'Developer' tools. For instance, in 'Google Chrome' you would press f12 on your keyboard, then on the window that opens, you would click, 'Sources' and select your file from the 'Navigator'.  Then you can breakpoint and step through your javascript.

Comment: If i change the type=submit to type=button, it is not working. Nothing is happening when i submit the button.

Comment: That's right.  You don't want the form to submit when you click the button.  You want it to submit after you click the button and your javascript validation happens. That's why you need to put the 'document.getElementById("myForm").submit();' code on the final line of your 'validateForm' function.  

If your form is not submitting after changing, your input type from 'submit' to 'button,' then you need to check your javascript to verify that it's working correctly.  Thus, you need to set breakpoints to verify that a. it's being called, and b. there are no errors.